# st terminal: Can't distinguish ctermfg=7 and ctermfg=15

Tags: vim, suckless-terminal

I've noticed that with default `config.h` of st, when I try to invoke `vim` inside `st`, there's no difference between white color `ctermfg=7` and `ctermfg=15`.

Here I expect `7` will have less-white than `15` but I see no difference with `:hi`

How to change this behavior?

Resolved: I change the correct color in array `colorname` and rebuild.

Answer (score 3):

```
% infocmp -1 st|grep -E '(colors|setaf)'
        colors#8,
        setaf=\E[3%p1%dm,
%
```

[The terminfo database entry for Simple Terminal](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.ti-entries.html#tic-st) tells the world that it supports 8 colours, and provides no mechanism for specifying more than 8 colours.  That world includes VIM and every other program that uses terminfo.

```
% infocmp -1 st-256color|grep -E '(colors|setaf)'
st-256color|stterm-256color|simpleterm with 256 colors,
        colors#256,
        setaf=\E[%?%p1%{8}%<%t3%p1%d%e%p1%{16}%<%t9%p1%{8}%-%d%e38;5;%p1%d%;m,
%
```

If you want to convince the (terminfo-using part of the) world that Simple Terminal supports 256 colours, and tell it how to use those 256 colours, you need to specify a different terminal type.

Comment: `st` does support 256 color.

Comment: And I just told you what to do to convince the world of that.